# How do I create a javascript object like this?

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I'm trying to create a javascript object like this:

```
data = { values:[
        { X: "Apples", Y: 120 },
        { X: "Oranges", Y: 280 },
        { X: "Chocolates", Y: 180 },
        { X: "Bananas", Y: 340 },
        { X: "Tomatoes", Y: 400 },
]};
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work?

```
var data = {};

for (i = 0; i < json.Answers.length; i++){
    data.values[i].X = json.Answers[i].AnswerText
    data.values[i].Y = json.Answers[i].Responses.length
    }
```

The json part is fine, any ideas on constructiong the object?

Comment: This can be done, but I strongly believe that an object that contains only one key is redundant. Wouldn't using just an array be better?

Comment: i need to pass this form of object, but I understand your advice for another usage.

Comment: Just as a side note: What you've called JSON above isn't JSON. In JSON, keys must be in double quotes (e.g. `"X": "Apples"` rather than `X: "Apples"`). What you quoted was a valid JavaScript object literal, but not JSON. JSON is a *subset* of object literal syntax.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply - I'm just taking the JSON and putting part of it into this graph object (hence the x and y axes)

Comment: @Joe: Right. But again, it's not JSON (the thing you've quoted at the top of your question). It's just a lot of people confuse the two, so I try to make sure to let people know when they call something JSON that isn't. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you're trying to use a `values` property of `data` that you've never defined. Change

```
var data = {};
```

to

```
var data = {values: []};
```

That creates the `values` array.

Also, in your loop you're trying to assign to objects that don't exist. Change the content of the loop to:

```
data.values[i] = {
    X: json.Answers[i].AnswerText,
    Y: json.Answers[i].Responses.length
};
```

That creates each object that goes in the `values` array as you build it.

So:

```
var data = {values: []};

for (i = 0; i < json.Answers.length; i++){
    data.values[i] = {
        X: json.Answers[i].AnswerText,
        Y: json.Answers[i].Responses.length
    };
}
```

---

(Side note: Don't forget to declare `i`, if it's not already declared, lest you fall prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).)

Answer (score 1):

#### Please initialize the `data` using:

```
data = {values: []};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data.values = [];

for (i = 0; i < json.Answers.length; i++) {
    data.values.push({X: json.Answers[i].AnswerText, Y: json.Answers[i].Responses.length});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var data = {values:[]};

for (i = 0; i < json.Answers.length; i++){
    data.values[i]= {X: json.Answers[i].AnswerText, Y:json.Answers[i].Responses.length}
}
```